# Google Geocoding API not returning San Francisco International Airport for SFO query

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

Up until recently, a query like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=SFO

was returning results including the San Francisco International Airport (SFO)...  this was/is desired behavior, and we were happy this was happening.

Today, I noticed that this no longer is the case.  Instead, it returns only one result which is an address in Denmark.

Does anyone know what has changed recently? and is there a way to get the previous result set behavior back?

Thanks for your help,

Tyler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also submitted a case to google support and it turns out they had an internal issue that was causing this.  They've resolved the issue and things are behaving as expected again.